# Nullspace with ejml

Tags: java, matrix, ejml

I am using a library called ejml (Efficient Java Matrix Library) and I am having some trouble trying to calculate the dimension of the nullspace from a Matrix.

First I tried with Singular Value Decomposition, but it gave me the error: "Decomposition failed".

And now I was wondering if working with QRPDecomposition could work.

But I dont know how to work with that library / how to make a matrix and calculate the nullspace. If you could put me some examples I will really appreciate

Comment: Did you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25098015/1813169)?

Comment: If the matrix is small you should paste it. Also if there's any NaN of infinite numbers in the input matrix that can cause problems.